# Increment number after event click

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please tell me why, when I click on check-icon, it adds the number only one time ?

```js
 const check1 = document.getElementById('1')

 check1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

 const value = document.getElementById('p1') 
 let x = 0
 if(e.target){
   x++   
   value.textContent = x  
   value.style.color = 'red'    
}  
 e.preventDefault() 

})
```

Comment: That's because x is initialized to 0 each time the listener is executed

Comment: haha , that is right :}    Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the variable x outside the addEventListener to increment its value on every checkbox action.

```js
const check1 = document.getElementById('1')
let x = 0;

check1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const value = document.getElementById('p1')

  if (e.target) {
    x++
    value.textContent = x
    value.style.color = 'red'
  }
  // e.preventDefault() 
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="1" />
<p id="p1"></p>
```

Comment: Yes it is working ,  I am beginner . trying some project ,, I was looking for this issue almost 20 minutes ... I could not find problem...  haha Beginner mistakes ...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Put the x outside the event handler else it will be set to x everytime the handler runs.

```
 let x = 0
 check1.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

 const value = document.getElementById('p1') 
 if(e.target){
   x++   
   value.textContent = x  
   value.style.color = 'red'    
}  
 e.preventDefault() 
})
```